# For what varieties do we have results on the category of singularities?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be a singular variety.  Define the (triangulated) category of singularities (as in Orlov's [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0503632))
as the Verdier quotient of the derived category of coherent sheaves on $X$ modulo the full subcategory of perfect complexes.

For example, there is a quiver description in the case of ADE surface singularities:
http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511155

Are there any other cases do we have results for the category of singularities?  In particular, for higher codimension varieties?

Comment: You'd better call it "(triangulated) category of singularities". Not to confuse with smoothness.

Comment: There are of course the cases of Landau-Ginzburg Calabi-Yau (and not Calabi-Yau!) correspondence See the papers of Orlov, Segal, Shipman, Itsik,... where the category of singularities can be related to the usual derived category of the critical locus.

Comment: Also Abouzaid, Auroux, Efimov, Katzarkov, Orlov make a computation in some explicit cases for their joint paper.

Comment: @user36931 Thanks for the reference.  Do you know a title for any of the papers by Orlov, Segal, Shipman, Itsik?  I'm having trouble finding them, possibly because I'm unfamiliar with what I should be looking for.

Comment: @AntonFonarev Thanks, I've edited the text.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5282 and references therein

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A student of Orlov is working on one case.  He will give a talk in two weeks in [Padova](http://events.math.unipd.it/hsaa/?q=node/5#), here is the abstract:

- Oleksandr Kravets (Moscow Higher School of Economics, Russia), *Exceptional collections in categories of singularities of 3-dimensional Landau-Ginzburg models*.

Abstract:
Derived categories of singularities measure how far is an algebraic variety
from being smooth. They appear on the algebraic side of the Homological
Mirror Symmetry (HMS) for the Landau-Ginzburg models. The talk will be
dedicated to the case when the superpotential is given by the so called
invertible polynomial. In the case of small dimensions, I will give
the description of mentioned categories in terms of full strongly exceptional collections
of good kind. I will also recall several conjectures concerning HMS for the
current case and will show how the constructed collections help to assert

Comment: Now this paper is posted on the arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09859