# Is there any explicit result on the triangulated category of singularities of a curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory, derived-categories

This question is related to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157004/for-what-varieties-do-we-have-results-on-the-category-of-singularities).

Let $X$ be a projective curve over a field $\mathbb{C}$. We have the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves $D^b_{coh}(X)$ and the derived category of perfect complex $Perf(X)$. It is clear that  $Perf(X)$ is a strictly full triangulated subcategory of  $D^b_{coh}(X)$. Then following [Orlov 2003](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0302304v2.pdf) we define the triangulated category of singularities of $X$ as the quotient of $D^b_{coh}(X)$ and  $Perf(X)$, i.e.
$$
D_{sg}(X)=D^b_{coh}(X)/Perf(X).
$$

Now is there any study of $D_{sg}(X)$ for the curve $X$? For example does  $D_{sg}(X)$ admit a semiorthogonal decomposition?

Comment: Just a comment: a semi-orthogonal decomposition of D^b_coh induces a semi-orthogonal decomposition of D_sg, according to Corollary 1.12 [here](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~orlov/papers/singnew.pdf).

Comment: @AdeelKhan Sure! Nevertheless for $X$ with arithmetic genus $\geq 1$, $D^b_{coh}(X)$ cannot have semiorthogonal decomposition but I wonder if $D_{sg}(X)$ still has.

Comment: Do you know a reference for that?  I only knew that fact in the smooth case.

Comment: @AdeelKhan After some thinking I should say that I only know it in the smooth case also. Sorry for the misleading. Nevertheless if we can compute the Grothendieck group of $D^b_{coh}(X)$ for singular curves $X$, it will be solved. I guess $K_0(D^b_{coh}(X))$ is not far from $K_0(D^b_{coh}(\widetilde{X}))$ where $\widetilde{X}\to X$ is the resolution of singularities but I don't know how to prove it.